# PHP 7.0.2 performs backtrace on error

Tags: php, xdebug, stack-trace

I'm running PHP version 7.0.2 on OS X El Capitan and every time I execute a PHP script that contains some erroneous code, it reports the error and then seems to perform a backtrace automatically. I'm not so sure if this is a new feature in PHP 7, however I cannot seem to find mention of it anywhere or anyone else who's facing a similar problem.

For Example:

```
<?php
   echo $a;
?>
```

Will return the following output if executed from CLI:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in /Path/to/file.php on line 2
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Path/to/file.php:0

Notice: Undefined variable: a in /Path/to/file.php on line 2

Call Stack:
    0.0002     350944   1. {main}() /Path/to/file.php:0
```

Any insight on what might be causing the problem is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: How is this a problem? I get the same info with php 5.6.10 on my computer. PHP7 might have improved it a bit, but it's not new. And it's a good thing!

Comment: jszobody The main reason I want to disable it is because I'm trying to migrate a fairly large project from PHP 5.6 and a large number of PHP Stack Trace statements seem to flood my terminal making it extremely difficult to sift through by comparison to what it's normal activity is to me. I suppose a better question is, is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Sure. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. You want to disable notices, most likely. Probably strict too.

Comment: posted as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was facing was not with PHP 7.0.2 itself, but with an extension that had somehow become enabled called XDebug. XDebug which is intended for advanced error reporting was causing problems in another project of mine and by disabling it, it seemed to solve my problem. In order to disable XDebug all you need to do is modify your php.ini file and change the values debug.remote_autostart, debug.default_enable, and debug.remote_enable from 'on' to 'off'.

Comment: It's too bad you have to disable XDebug.  I can't imagine life without it on my dev server!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `xdebug.default_enable=0` to `php.ini` will prevent XDebug from sending stack traces without giving up profiling and debugging capabilities.